# Take data weights into account when using dplyr:count [R]

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working with purely factorial data (survey), and I need to aggregate the data in order to visualise it. I am currently using the count() function from dplyr, but there is no option to take data weights into account. In particular, I want count() to count each row as its given weight.

Currently `count(data, var1, var2, var3)` returns an aggregated dataframe where each row from `data` is counted as 1. I want to be able to specify a numeric weight column within my `data` so that each row is counted as the value in `data$weight` in stead of simply 1.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could repeat the rows `data$weight` times and then count. This can be done with the `splitstackshape` package:

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(dplyr)

mydf <- data.frame(x = c("a", "b", "q","a","b"), 
                   y = c("c", "d", "r","c","r"), 
                   count = c(2, 5, 3,4,4))
mydf

  x y count
1 a c     2
2 b d     5
3 q r     3
4 a c     4
5 b r     4


mydf %>% 
  expandRows("count") %>% 
  count(x)

  x y n
1 a c 6
2 b d 5
3 b r 4
4 q r 3
```

Comment: Thanks that's very useful! Is there a way to make this possible for non-integer weights?